# Problem with oracle forms 12c installation

Tags: weblogic, oracleforms

I am trying to install Oracle 12c forms on my local pc. When I try to select
the path of my instaled Oracle 12c weblogic (I have instaled oracle 12c database and 12c weblogic)
and click next in the installation wizard it says

INST-07548: The selected distribution does not have any compatible install type for the selected Oracle Home.
INST-07551: Not all dependent featuresets for install type "Forms and Reports Deployment" could be found. The following prerequisites were found to be missing:
em_fmc - 12.2.1.3.0

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

have you followed the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/formsandreports/install-fnr/install.htm#FRINS101) ?
I must admit that installing Oracle Forms and Reports is not really straightforward.
You have to stick to what's said in the documentation, by first installing the "Oracle WebLogic Server FMW Infrastructure" and then install "Forms and Reports" product over it.

Comment: I read the instructions (not all documentation). The database 12c works perfectly and I managed to install weblogic without any problem. The files that I got are from the offical oracle site for downloads. I know that is not easy to install and configure these kind of programs because I have experience in working with forms but I was supraised with these type of error. I will read the all documentations to see If I have missed somenthing.

Comment: yes, sorry if I sounded rude but I lost a lot of time by trying to install Forms without following any documentation. The points with the Weblogic domain creation and any patches can be painful if you try to go your own way.
Also it seems your question have been adresses on other forum, like http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/202071/0/

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Forms and Reports is not install directly . First install the "Oracle WebLogic Server ,FMW Infrastructure" and then install " Forms and Reports.

Comment: This adds nothing to the [answer provided by R. Du](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55627568/10871073) some nine months ago.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to download the Infrastructure version of WebLogic Server.
I think that is what you miss from all the answers and tries. :)
also this worked from me .