# Oracle Form: INST-07548: The selected distribution does not have any compatible install type for the selected Oracle Home

Tags: oracleforms

I have installed web logic server and then trying to install oracle form and reports. After skip update option I selected C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home this directory for installation location where I installed the web logic server. But it's telling

> INST-07551: Not all dependent featuresets for install type "Forms and
> Reports Deployment" could be found. The following prerequisites were
> found to be missing: em_fmc - 12.2.1.4.0wls_server - 12.2.1.4.0

How to get rid of this so I can successfully install the oracle from .

Comment: Install the prerequisites first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with oracle forms 12c installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621781/problem-with-oracle-forms-12c-installation)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use "Weblogic Server" installs.  You must use "Fusion Middlewware Infrastructure", which is WLS plus special pieces needed by Forms/Reports.

[image]

Comment: I am using Fusion Middleware Infrastructure 12.2.1.4(1.5gb)

Comment: And are you installing F/R into the FMW home?